# Are these two block matrices Hurwitz？

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, hurwitz-matrices

Define$$H_1=\left( \begin{matrix}
   -A & B  \\
   -{{B}^{T}} & 0  \\
\end{matrix} \right),$$

where $A\in {{\mathbb{R}}^{n\times n}}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. $B\in {{\mathbb{R}}^{n\times m}}$ is a column full rank matrix with $n<m$. Can we prove that $H_1$ is a Hurwitz Matrix (all the eigenvalues have negative real parts)?

Moreover, let $G\in {{\mathbb{R}}^{n\times n}}$ be symmetric negative definite.
Define$$H_2=\left( \begin{matrix}
   AG & B  \\
   {{B}^{T}G} & 0  \\
\end{matrix} \right).$$
Can we prove that $H_2$ is a Hurwitz Matrix?